# Is there a way to enforce case sensitivity of the names of files in a VB.Net project?

Tags: vb.net, case-sensitive

Question says it all. Is there a way to enforce case sensitivity in VB.Net file-names? If so, how!

The primary issue that I am trying to solve is the difference in how Windows doesn't care about the case of a file-name, but other tools, like Subversion, *do* care about the case of a file-name

Comment: Well for what its worth, C# == VB.NET with a little different syntax. Come, join us, the cult of the curly brace...

Comment: @Juliet - I would love to, but resistance to change is strong here, and the general mentality is "if it ain't broke, don't fix it"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, by writing your own compiler.

New answer for the new question - you're probably better off trying to make your other tools operate in a case-insensitive way in regards to filenames. For example, here's a [pre-commit hook for subversion that checks for case-insensitive filename clashes](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/case-insensitive.py).

Comment: Wow - the question changed completely. How nice.

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET is not designed to support that, no.  If case sensitivity is high on your priority list, I would recommend trying a language that does support it.  C# comes to mind, and the transition really isn't that bad.

EDIT:  Oops, it looks like you changed your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the Windows API that doesn't care about the casing of filenames, not the programming language.